# Calling parent constructors in R with multiple inheritance

Tags: r, multiple-inheritance, r-s4

I'm trying to have a class call its parent constructors, but callNextMethod only calls the first parent. Namely, if I have

```
setClass('A')
setClass('B')
setClass('C', contains = c('A','B'))
```

and define initialize methods for all three, printing 'In A', 'In B', and 'In C', respectively, with a callNextMethod in the initialize method of C, then it only prints 'In A'. Is there a way to dispatch all the constructors?

(And yes, I know multiple inheritance is bad; I'm trying to implement the notion of mixins and this happens to be the most appropriate way to do it)